# How to generate a Polygon with N sides (equal length and angles)

Tags: javascript, math, svg, geometry, polygon

I am looking for a way to calculate the SVG path for a regular polygon given the number of sides, the width and height of the wrapper-container.

Any help will be really appreciated!

Thank you,
Best.

Update: N could be both even and odd.

Comment: Depends on `N`, if it is even or odd.

Comment: Hey @Teemu it should cater for both cases. I am editing the question

Comment: Have you got the numbers figured out ?  In other words, where are you stuck ?  With the maths or with the code ?

Answer (score 0):

Step 1. How to create SVG

```
 const $svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg")
 $svg.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/", "xmlns:xlink", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink")
 $svg.setAttribute('width', 500)
 $svg.setAttribute('height', 500)
 $svg.setAttribute('viewBox', '0 0 500 500')
 document.body.appendChild($svg)
```

Step 2. How to create Line

```
const $el= document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "line")
$el.setAttribute('x1', 0)
$el.setAttribute('y1', 0)
$el.setAttribute('x2', 100) // not real
$el.setAttribute('y2', 100) // not real
$svg.appendChild($el)
```

Step 3. How to create real Line

```
function (sides, width) {
    const angle = 360 / sides

    const $el1= document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "line")
    $el1.setAttribute('x1', 0)
    $el1.setAttribute('y1', 0)
    $el1.setAttribute('x2', width)
    $el1.setAttribute('y2', 0)
    $svg.appendChild($el1)

    // we already created first line, so start from 1
    for (var i = 1; i < sides.length; i++) { 
        const $el= document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "line")     
        const offsetX_angle = 180 - angle
        const hypotenuse = width / Math.sin(90)
        const offsetX = Math.sin(90 - offsetX_angle) * hypotenuse
        const offsetY = Math.sin(offsetX_angle) * hypotenuse

        // now we know the offsets
        // and we can easily populate other lines using same offset
        const x1 = width
        const y1 = 0
        const x2 = width + offsetX
        const y2 = 0 + offsetY

        // just need to switch angles based in i
    }
}
```

This is not full solution, it's steps for making solution

[image]